# how to update serializer.validated_data in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

good day

me need update validated_data dict

example

```
class ProductsApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

def post(self, request):
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    product = serializer.save()
    print(serializer.validated_data)
    return Response({'message': 'created'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)



class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['my_data'] = 'my_new_data'
        return super(ProductSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title']
```

when i make  print(serializer.validated_data)

```
OrderedDict([('title', 'testttt')])
```

why in dict no my data "my_data" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide arbitrary additional context by passing a context argument when instantiating the serializer. For example:

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(account, context={'request': request})
serializer.data
```

The context dictionary can be used within any serializer field logic, such as a custom .to_representation() method, by accessing the self.context attribute.

[Reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)